# Which of the Japanese scripts should I learn first?

Tags: academic-japanese

When do we use kanji, katakana and hiragana?
Which of these should I study first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common method is to learn Hiragana first, and then Katakana. When you are comfortable with those, you can begin learning kanji.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that describes the three alphabets a bit and gives you a starting point.

https://www.fluentin3months.com/japanese-alphabet/